# Android Studio 3 Stable Text Blurry on IDE

Tags: android-studio

i've update to Android Studio 3 Stable. But, why my IDE Text blurry? anyone have same issue?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: dont see anything blurry in that screenshot, also i updated it 2 days ago, all looks fine

Comment: seriously, i got it blurry in my mac.

Comment: i also use a mac :P